# Adobe AIR command key on a mac not detected

Tags: actionscript-3, air, keyboard, adobe

I currently developing and AIR app for what I need to detect the command key for a combo key, currently I have something like this

```
this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

protected function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if(event.ctrlKey){
    switch(event.keyCode){
      case Keyboard.C:
      trace("need to copy");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

according to the docs event.ctrlKey, should detect command and control key on the mac, if I press the combo control + C works, but if I use command + c nothing, I also have tried

```
event.commandKey
```

I thought that maybe the built-in menu is given me some troubles, I remove then and still nothing, what I'm missing? thanks for any help

Comment: How have you tried using `event.commandKey`? Did you replace `event.ctrlKey` or did you add it to the conditional with "and"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced the same issue and made a workaround for that by adding native menu event for clipboard Keys. As you told "event.ctrlKey" don't work for MAC and "command key" in combination with C(copy), V(paste), X(cut), W(close), M(minimize) will always listen to native menu event (buildIn menu event) of the AIR application. So i added menu select event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey_PressHandler);
            }

            protected function onKey_PressHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                // for mac only statements
                if(isMAC())
                {
                    if(NativeApplication.supportsMenu){
                        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.COMMAND)
                        {
                            if(event.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN)
                            {
                                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,onApplicationMenu_ClickHandler);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // remove event if it is no longer needed 
                                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT,onApplicationMenu_ClickHandler);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            protected function onApplicationMenu_ClickHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                var menuItem:NativeMenuItem = event.target as NativeMenuItem; 

                switch(menuItem.label)
                {
                    case "cut":
                        // do cut operation
                        trace("COMMAND + X");
                        break;
                    case "copy":
                        // do copy operation
                        trace("COMMAND + C");
                        break;
                    case "paste":
                        // do paste operation
                        trace("COMMAND + V");
                        break;
                }
            }

            private function isMAC():Boolean
            {
                return (Capabilities.version.substr(0,3) == "mac");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

i hope this will fix your problem...